# OpenCV Bitwise_and function in Emgu

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

How can I use Bitwise_and function in Emgu? I found it in Emgu wiki [Bitwise_and](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/f5ad1313-323f-4ec1-cb9e-97f699ff2908.htm) but I don't know how to call it !

I'm trying to convert that code from c++ to c# [Tuto](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/)

Answer (score 2):

See the methode signature : ***CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd***(IInputArray **src1**, IInputArray **src2**, IOutputArray **dst**, IInputArray **mask** = null)

Let's take an example: 
[im1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK75A.png),[im2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQVY.png)

```
        Mat im1 = new Mat(path + "im1.png", LoadImageType.Grayscale);
        Mat im2 = new Mat(path + "im2.png", LoadImageType.Grayscale);

        Mat im1andim2 = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd(im1, im2, im1andim2);
        im1andim2.Save(path + "im1andim2.png");
```

which give : 
[im1andim2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drs7P.png)

If you need to use a mask, proceed like this:

Let's take this mask: [msk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjqdb.png)

```
        Mat msk = new Mat(path + "msk.png", LoadImageType.Grayscale);
        Mat im1andim2Masked = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd(im1, im2, im1andim2Masked, msk);
        im1andim2Masked.Save(path + "im1andim2Masked.png");
```

This time the resulting image is : [im1andim2Masked.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JYWi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just use & as an normal operator like a plus in 1 + 2.

Use This :

```
resultPic = firstPic & secondPic;
```